# Swift - How to Change Multi-Level JSON Struct Single Element Value on Condition

Tags: swift, struct, multi-level

I have multi-level Struct that converts complex JSON data to a Struct. What I am struggling is to change the dataStruct.group.point.presentValue element value on condition.

```
var dataStruct : DataStruct = load("jsonfile.json")

 struct DataStruct : Codable {
    let name: String
    var group: [groupData]
}

struct groupData: Codable, Hashable {
    let id, name : String
    var point : [pointInfo]

}

struct pointInfo : Codable, Hashable {
    let id : String
    let address : address
    let name : String
    var presentValue : String
}

struct address: Codable, Hashable {
    let index: String
    let type: String
}
```

I have tried the following map function, but the compiler complains that the Group in ForEach is 'let' constant.
Basically the function is supposed to compare *address.index* field in the Struct to the passed *pointNo* variable, and once it has been found (unique), point.presentValue is changed to the new value.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

```
   func updatePresentValue(pointNo : String) {
        
        dataStruct.group.forEach { Group in
            Group.point = Group.point.map { point -> pointInfo in

                var p = point
                if point.address.index == pointNo {
                    p.presentValue = "New value"
                    return p
                }
                else { return p }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two ways.

- Extract the objects by assigning them to variables, modify them and reassign them to their position in `dataStruct`.
- `Enumerate` the arrays and modify the objects in place.

This is an example of the second way

```
func updatePresentValue(pointNo : String) {
    for (groupIndex, group) in dataStruct.group.enumerated() {
        for (pointIndex, point) in group.point.enumerated() {
            if point.address.index == pointNo {
                dataStruct.group[groupIndex].point[pointIndex].presentValue = "New value"
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets more complicated when dealing with multilevel structures but here is one way to do it where we first enumerate over `group` so we get both the object and the index of the object for each iteration so we can use this index when updating the `group` array. The inner struct is updated using a mutable copy of `point`

```
for (index, group) in dataStruct.group.enumerated() {
    if group.point.contains(where: { $0.address.index == pointNo }) {
        var copy = group
        copy.point = group.point.reduce(into: []) {
            if $1.address.index == pointNo {
                var pointCopy = $1
                pointCopy.presentValue = "new value"
                $0.append(pointCopy)
            } else {
                $0.append($1)
            }
        }
        dataStruct.group[index] = copy
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - using the enumeration it works!